# How can execute a shell script from spotlight on macOS passing a first command line argument?

Tags: python, bash, macos

I have written a python program that needs a first command line argument to run from the Terminal. The program can be used to copy a text to the clipboard when it is run with a certain keyword.

```
~ python3 mclip.py 'agree'
```

This use case is just an exercise to understand, how I can run a batch file on macOS (or shell script in macOS terminology).

I have created the following shell script and saved it as `mclip.command`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python3 /Users/Andrea_5K/mclip.py
```

My idea is to execute my shell script from the spotlight input window, passing the argument 'agree'. How can I do that?

On windows the batch file would look like that (`mclip.bat`):

```
@py.exe C:\path_to_my_file\mclip.py %*
@pause
```

I can press WIN-R and type `mclip *argument*` to run the program. But how can I do the same on a Mac? I cannot type `mclip agree` in spotlight, that doesn't work like in WIN-R.

```
#! python3
# mclip.py - A multi-clipboard program.

TEXT = {
    'agree': """Yes, I agree. That sounds fine to me.""",
    'busy': """Sorry, can we do this later this week or next week?""",
    'upsell': """Would you consider making this a monthly donation?""",
}

import sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: python mclip.py [keyphrase] - copy phrase text')
    sys.exit()

keyphrase = sys.argv[1] # first command line arg is the keyphrase

if keyphrase in TEXT:
    pyperclip.copy(TEXT[keyphrase])
    print('Text for ' + keyphrase + ' copied to clipboard.')
else:
    print('There is no text for ' + keyphrase)
```

Comment: Since mac is unix based, its more like linux than windows. The very first command should work on MAC imo.

Comment: Err, why don't you put a shebang with python3 in your Python script directly? env python3 works exactly like env bash?!

Comment: If you always need to provide `agree` as an argument, why don't you modify the script not to need it? Or provide the argument within the script?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I do not always want 'agree' as the first command line argument. It can be any one word string. My program just fetches sys.argv[1] argument and uses whatever word was typed in on the command line.

Comment: I did a couple of tests and it seems Spotlight doesn't want you to do this. I have deleted my answer so as not to put off other potential answerers. Let's see if anyone comes up with a working solution. An alternative might be to make a double-clickable script on your Desktop, which does work.

Comment: The critical part might be: how to tell spotlight in which path to look? Meaning: even when your script is executable, and sits say in some $HOME / bin folder ... that only affects a shell session. Meaning: spotlight searches specific "locations" for things that can be executed. Having some file sitting somewhere in the file system isnt that.

Comment: @GhostCat sounds logic, but I mean on Windows with WIN+R it is possible to enter the stem of a file and pass an argument. So that means, Windows just has a feature here that macOS doesn't have? Well, that might be...:-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assume the shell script (mapIt.command) is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python3 /path/to/my/pythonScript.py $@
```

The $@ is interpreted as a list of command line arguments.

I can run the shell script in the MacOS Terminal like that:

```
sh mapIt.command Streetname Number City
```

The command line arguments *Streetname* *Number* *City* are forwarded to the python script.

Comment: So how did you manage to run this from spotlight?

Answer (score 5):

I can get Spotlight to run a script which:

- offers you a dialog box with your three options and
- then runs your Python script passing the selected option

But I cannot get Spotlight to pass an option to a Python script directly. If that helps, here's how to do it.

---

Start **Script Editor** and enter the following code, save it as an `app` called `mclip`:

```
set theArg to choose from list {"Agree", "Busy", "Upsell"} with title "Chooser Dialog" with prompt "Choose option"

tell application "Terminal"
    do shell script "/Users/YOURNAME/mclip.py " & theArg
end tell
```

Note that adding `on run argv` at the top still doesn't get you any arguments you add within Spotlight - it just plain doesn't seem to want to pass on any arguments you type in the Spotlight dialog.

---

Now write a Python script called `$HOME/mclip.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os, sys

 # Just write the received parameter into a text file on the Desktop to show how it works
file = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/result.txt")
with open(file, 'w') as f:
   f.write(sys.argv[1])
```

And make it executable (just necessary one time) with:

```
chmod +x $HOME/mclip.py
```

If you now use **Spotlight** to run `mclip`, it will pop up a dialog like this:

[image]

You may have to answer security questions the first time you run it - depending on your macOS version.

Note that if all your Python script does is copy some text onto the clipboard, you can do that without Python within the Applescript above using:

```
set the clipboard to "Some funky text"
```

Comment: Ok, I have done that, but how can I use the spotlight, now? Typing in mclip.command and then giving a keyword does not work...the keyword I pass is used to reference the dictionary in my program. It fetches the value and pastes it to the clipboard for further use. I am just wondering if - on macOS - I have the same option to run a shell script like Windows users can run a batch file from the "Run window" on a Windows PC...as I mentioned it is possible to type *mclip key phrase* into the Run window.

Comment: Wow, that looks great! It's far more from what I have expected but I really appreciate your effort. Your code covers concepts that are new to me but I will gladly read your code, be it just as a good exercise, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a detail: python is case sensitive. So, if the keys of the dictionary are lower case, the list values in the apple script ought to be lower case to `:D

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31181716)